# Deletion of all but the first channel in a cell of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-structures, subset, cell-array

I have a row cell vector `M`, containing matrices in each cell. Every matrix `m` (matrix inside the big matrix `M`) is made of 2 channels (columns), of which I only want to use the first.

The approach I thought about was going through each `m`, check if it has 2 channels, and if that is the case delete the second channel. 
Is there a way to just slice it in matlab? or loop it and obtain the matrix `M` as the matrix `m` would disappear.

First code is:

```
   load('ECGdata.mat')
```

I have the below.

[image]

when I double-click in one of the variable , here is what I can see:

[image]

As you can see the length of each matrix in each cell is different. Now let's see one cell:

[image]

The loop I'm trying to get must check the shape of the matrix (I'm talking python here/ I mean if the matrix has 2 columns then delete the second) because some of the variables of the dataframe have matrix containing one column (or just a normal column).

In here I'm only showing the `SR` variable that has 2 columns for each matrix. Its not the case for the rest of the variables

Comment: Can you define `channels` ? Please share input and expected output.

Comment: It isn't very difficult to do, but we must know what your data structure looks like exactly. For example, you seem to use the word _matrix_ when you probably mean _cell_. Regarding channels, does that mean 3d arrays (2 spatial dimensions + 1 color dimension?) or are you talking about vectors with 2 rows/columns?

Comment: Ideally, you’d specify all of this explicitly by posting a bit of code that creates a matrix structure like you have here (with example data, even if it is filled with zeros).

Comment: @Dev-iL. yes I mean  each  cell contains a matrix and yes again it could  understand vectors or columns within the cells.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. I just loaded the data using the matlab load function. It is sample of a signal. So I basically have some kind of a dataframe with about 200 columns and one row. Each cell containing a matrix with 2 columns. I litteraly have to  double click on the cell  to view as they dont have same length.

Comment: @Herc01 you must understand that for us to provide you a solution, we have to know the structure of your data  **exactly**. This is why Cris asked you to provide some code that creates a _similar_ data structure (i.e. matrices of varying sizes inside a cell vector). The more representative your example, the better the solution you could potentially get. If you are unable to write code that generates this data, you can upload a `.mat` file somewhere (although this generally isn't a good practice on SO).

Comment: @Dev-iL  it has been updated now

Comment: @CrisLuengo it has been updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to *delete* the extra "channel", what you can do is quite simple:

```
newVar = cellfun(@(x)x(:,1), varName, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

where `varName` is `SR`, `VF` etc. (just run this command once for each of the variables you load).

What the code above does is go over each element of the input cell (an Nx2 matrix in your example), and select the first column only. Then it stores all outputs in a new cell array. In case of matrices with a single column, there is no effect - we just get the input back.

(I apologize in advance if there is some typo / error in the code, as I am writing this answer from my phone and cannot test it. Please leave a comment if something is wrong, and I'll do my best to fix it tomorrow.)

Comment: Boom!!! thank you  well explained as well. i would have never guessed it. well its my first day on matlab. But thanks, it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Herc01 You're welcome, glad it helped! I hope you understand now why we insisted that you show us the structure of your data - otherwise it's impossible to establish a regularity, and write code that generalizes well. We were all beginners once :). BTW, as a general tip for the future - what you asked is known as an "[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)", where instead of asking for what you _need_ (aka "X"), you asked us about the implementation that you though about (aka "Y") you should be careful about it in the future, as it might result in worse answers for you.